# Pass PHP variable to Javascript won't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have two different pages for my site, lets call them page1 and page2. On the first page I have a HTML form of which handles some information. Then I have a php document to process that information into a .txt file. Then I have an image on my page2, this image I would like to change depending on a specific variable. This variable is set in the php script, where it checks if a certain value is right then it will set this specific variable to either 1 or 2. Then as said on page2 I have this image I would like to change depending on whether the php variable is 1 or 2. This I am trying to do by getting the php variable through javascript on page2 and then displaying it first to make sure I am getting the right values. But when doing this I just get "null" and pretty much nothing really happens. It loads the page but doesn't display anything. Keep in mind when I am saying pages etc it is because the page1 is one HTML document, page2 is another HTML document and then of course the php function is a separate php document.

### HTML page1 where the user would pick from a drop down menu

```
<div id="sKind">
     <select border="0" size="1" name="produKind" id="cSK" data-selected="" required="">
        <option value="">enter color</option>
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

### php file I am using to pass values and variables

```
<?php

    $field_skind = $_POST['produKind'];

    $imgShow = 1;
    if ($field_skind == white){
      $imgShow = 1;
    } else if ($field_skind == black) {
      $imgShow = 2;
    }
    echo json_encode($imgShow);
?>
```

### Code I am using on page2 html

```
<script>

var imgNumber = <?php echo json_encode($imgShow)?>;

document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = imgNumber;

</script>

<p id="insert"></p>
```

Comment: post the result of this: `var imgNumber = <?php echo json_encode($imgShow)?>;`

Comment: You are doing things incorrectly, try looking for a simple AJAX tutorial there are hundereds on the web.

Comment: If page 2 is `.html` you can't put PHP on it. Also, where is that PHP var coming from? They don't just carry over from file to file.

Comment: You don't need to use json_encode if your variable is a number, you only need it for more complex structures, such as arrays or objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable only exists within the program it appears it.

A separate HTML document isn't the same program. It isn't a program at all.

If you want to use the variable, then you need to generate the content of page 2 from *that* PHP program.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I actually didn't know I was able to just put it all into one code. I have figured it out and it works now. Your help is much appreciated.